# Long life to Android Service: "immortal service"

Tags: android, android-service

Reading 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
and
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html i have read two important statement: 
1) There are two reasons that a service can be run by the system. If someone **calls Context.startService()** then the system will retrieve the service (creating it and calling its onCreate() method if needed) and then call its onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method with the arguments supplied by the client. **The service will at this point continue running until Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called.** 
2) A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API to put the service in a foreground state, where **the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory.** (It is still theoretically possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure from the current foreground application, but in practice this should not be a concern.) 

My aim is to create a remote service running in separate process (declaring android:process on Manifest) and ensure that the process is always active, unless the Android S.O. reclaim memory.

What contraindications are there and what are the differences between these 3 different implementations?

Calling startService() from onBind():

```
public class ExampleService extends Service {

    ...

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        startService(new Intent(this, ExampleService.class));
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    ...

}
```

Calling startForegorund() from onCreate():

```
public class ExampleService extends Service {

    ...

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ...
        startForeground(ord, note);
    }

    ...

}
```

Calling startForegorund() from onCreate() and startService from onBind():

```
public class ExampleService extends Service {

    ...

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        startService(new Intent(this, ExampleService.class));
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ...
        startForeground(ord, note);
    }

    ...

}
```

The clients will use this Service calling bindService() and using IBinder.

Comment: Did you find any answer for your question,I have a project and I deal with same problem.I want to have a long life service that read some sensor values(like proximity) and I want it continue working even if user close main activity.May you kindly help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have more information about this 3 use cases, i have tried this three cases and for each one I took "dumpsys activity processes" after start app, bound service, and putting activity in background (pressing home button):

First case (only calling startService() in onBind()):

```
*APP* UID 10137 ProcessRecord{40b01d30 6719:com.mypackage:service_process/10137}            
    class=com.mypackage.app.MyApp                                                             
    dir=/data/app/com.mypackage-1.apk publicDir=/data/app/com.mypackage-1.apk data=/data/data/com.mypackage
    packageList=[com.mypackage]                                                               
    thread=android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@40d1b540 curReceiver=null                       
    pid=6719 starting=false lastPss=0                                                         
    lastActivityTime=-1m42s491ms lruWeight=671144 keeping=true hidden=false empty=true        
    oom: max=15 hidden=8 curRaw=4 setRaw=4 cur=4 set=4                                        
    curSchedGroup=1 setSchedGroup=1                                                           
    setIsForeground=false foregroundServices=false forcingToForeground=null                   
    persistent=false removed=false                                                            
    adjSeq=5157 lruSeq=1017                                                                   
    lastRequestedGc=-1m46s82ms lastLowMemory=-1m46s82ms reportLowMemory=false                 
    services=[ServiceRecord{40a68aa0 com.mypackage/.model.page.ServerConnection}]             
    connections=[ConnectionRecord{40d11118 com.mypackage/.util.CommonService:@40d12928}, ConnectionRecord{40bca008 com.mypackage/.model.page.ServerConnection:@40d0bd08}, ConnectionRecord{40d64030 com.mypackage/.util.log.LoggerService:@40d34b38}]

Running processes (most recent first):                                                      
    Proc #16: adj=svc  /B 40b01d30 6719:com.mypackage:service_process/10137 (started-services)
```

Second case (only calling startForeground() in onCreate()):

```
*APP* UID 10137 ProcessRecord{40c47420 7921:com.mypackage:service_process/10137}
    class=com.mypackage.app.MyApp
    dir=/data/app/com.mypackage-2.apk publicDir=/data/app/com.mypackage-2.apk data=/data/data/com.mypackage
    packageList=[com.mypackage]
    thread=android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@40a044c8 curReceiver=null
    pid=7921 starting=false lastPss=0
    lastActivityTime=-27s701ms lruWeight=1232643 keeping=true hidden=false empty=false
    oom: max=15 hidden=8 curRaw=2 setRaw=2 cur=2 set=2
    curSchedGroup=0 setSchedGroup=0
    setIsForeground=false foregroundServices=true forcingToForeground=null
    persistent=false removed=false
    adjSeq=6068 lruSeq=1170
    lastRequestedGc=-32s123ms lastLowMemory=-32s123ms reportLowMemory=false
    services=[ServiceRecord{40b3b1d0 com.mypackage/.model.page.ServerConnection}]
    connections=[ConnectionRecord{40b18da8 com.mypackage/.util.log.LoggerService:@40b18b88}, ConnectionRecord{40c86fa0 com.mypackage/.model.page.ServerConnection:@40c86d80}, ConnectionRecord{40c869a0 com.mypackage/.util.CommonService:@409626c8}]

Running processes (most recent first):
    Proc #18: adj=prcp /F 40c47420 7921:com.mypackage:service_process/10137 (foreground-service)
```

Third case (calling either: startService() in onBind() and startForeground() in onCreate()):

```
*APP* UID 10137 ProcessRecord{40d35d30 8407:com.mypackage:service_process/10137}
    class=com.mypackage.app.MyApp
    dir=/data/app/com.mypackage-1.apk publicDir=/data/app/com.mypackage-1.apk data=/data/data/com.mypackage
    packageList=[com.mypackage]
    thread=android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@40a6f7a0 curReceiver=null
    pid=8407 starting=false lastPss=0
    lastActivityTime=-6s98ms lruWeight=1423485 keeping=true hidden=false empty=false
    oom: max=15 hidden=7 curRaw=2 setRaw=2 cur=2 set=2
    curSchedGroup=0 setSchedGroup=0
    setIsForeground=false foregroundServices=true forcingToForeground=null
    persistent=false removed=false
    adjSeq=6565 lruSeq=1289
    lastRequestedGc=-10s334ms lastLowMemory=-10s334ms reportLowMemory=false
    services=[ServiceRecord{40ba7650 com.mypackage/.model.page.ServerConnection}]
    connections=[ConnectionRecord{40ac5408 com.mypackage/.model.page.ServerConnection:@40ac5228}, ConnectionRecord{40c760e8 com.mypackage/.util.CommonService:@40c31fa8}, ConnectionRecord{40c31c00 com.mypackage/.util.log.LoggerService:@40bc4bf0}]

Running processes (most recent first):
    Proc #13: adj=prcp /F 40d35d30 8407:com.mypackage:service_process/10137 (foreground-service)
```

The default case (not calling startService() and startForeground(), but only binding service):

```
*APP* UID 10137 ProcessRecord{40c3eb78 5609:com.mypackage:service_process/10137}
    class=com.mypackage.app.MyApp
    dir=/data/app/com.mypackage-2.apk publicDir=/data/app/com.mypackage-2.apk data=/data/data/com.mypackage
    packageList=[com.mypackage]
    thread=android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@40a34c90 curReceiver=null
    pid=5609 starting=false lastPss=0
    lastActivityTime=-5m31s175ms lruWeight=227344 keeping=false hidden=true empty=true
    oom: max=15 hidden=7 curRaw=7 setRaw=7 cur=7 set=7
    curSchedGroup=1 setSchedGroup=1
    setIsForeground=false foregroundServices=false forcingToForeground=null
    persistent=false removed=false
    adjSeq=4483 lruSeq=887
    lastWakeTime=0 time used=0
    lastCpuTime=0 time used=0
    lastRequestedGc=-2m1s649ms lastLowMemory=-6m7s191ms reportLowMemory=false
    services=[ServiceRecord{40d559b8 com.mypackage/.model.page.ServerConnection}]
    connections=[ConnectionRecord{40beeef0 com.mypackage/.model.page.ServerConnection:@40bd4620}, ConnectionRecord{40bc4c60 com.mypackage/.util.CommonService:@40b69ea0}, ConnectionRecord{40ac74b0 com.mypackage/.util.log.LoggerService:@40ab5d60}]

Running processes (most recent first):
    Proc #22: adj=bak+3/B 40c3eb78 5609:com.mypackage:service_process/10137 (bg-empty)
```

I think the most important thing is **the value of adj** that changes in all cases and assumes these values:

1) svc

2) prcp

3) bak